# Does this "inverse Taylor series" exist in literature?

Tags: reference-request, power-series, taylor-expansion, approximation-theory

So next in my list of (my) useless ideas here's the idea of an "inverse Taylor series"...enjoy!

Let $f$ be an analytic function, so that
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n
\end{equation}
The idea is that since
\begin{equation}
f(kx)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n k^nx^n=:f_k(x)
\end{equation}
one could try to rewrite a power of $x$, say $x^m$, in terms of the $f_k(x)$'s:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} c_k f_k(x) = x^m
\end{equation}
Noting that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} c_k f_k(x) = \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} c_k \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nk^nx^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} c_ka_nk^n\right)x^n
\end{equation}
we would have the condition
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} c_k f_k(x) = x^m
\qquad\Longrightarrow\qquad
\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} c_ka_nk^n = \delta_{mn}
\end{equation}
which is an infinite-dimensional linear system in the unknowns $c_k$. It reminds me in some weird way of a Fourier expansion.

As an example, I tried to "reverse-expand" $f(x)=x$ with a series of exponentials (truncating their Taylor expansion at the fourth power of $x$ because I don't remember how to handle infinite-dimensional linear systems).

$$e^{-2x}=1-2x+2x^2-\frac{4}{3}x^3-\frac{2}{3}x^4$$
$$e^{-x}=1-x+\frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{6}x^3+\frac{1}{24}x^4$$
$$e^{0}=1\qquad\text{(duh)}$$
$$e^x=1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{6}x^3+\frac{1}{24}x^4$$
$$e^{2x}=1+2x+2x^2+\frac{4}{3}x^3+\frac{2}{3}x^4$$

so we have
\begin{equation}
x=c_{-2}e^{-2x}+c_{-1}e^{-x}+c_0e^0+c_1e^x+c_2e^{2x}=
(c_{-2}+c_{-1}+c_0+c_1+c_2)+(-2c_{-2}-c_{-1}+c_1+2c_2)x+\left(2c_{-2}+\frac{c_{-1}}{2}+\frac{c_1}{2}+2c_2\right)x^2+\left(-\frac{4}{3}c_{-2}-\frac{c_{-1}}{6}+\frac{c_1}{6}+\frac{4}{3}c_2\right)x^3+\left(-\frac{2}{3}c_{-2}+\frac{c_{-1}}{24}+\frac{c_1}{24}+\frac{2}{3}c_2\right)x^4
\end{equation}

This yields a $5x5$ linear system in the unknowns $c_{-2},c_{-1}, c_0, c_1, c_2$ which has a unique solution:

\begin{equation}
c_{-2}=-\frac{1}{4},\qquad c_{-1}=\frac{2}{3}, \qquad c_0=-2, \qquad c_1 = 2, \qquad c_2 = -\frac{5}{12} 
\end{equation}
The resulting function is
\begin{equation}
f(x)=-\frac{1}{4}e^{-2x}+\frac{2}{3}e^{-x}-2+2e^x-\frac{5}{12}e^{2x}
\end{equation}
graphed here along with the desired function $x$:

[image: Inverse Taylor approximant]

which "feels plausible" since we've worked with the truncated series...

My question(s):

(1) How do I approach infinite-dimensional linear systems of this type and are there any convergence problems or other dangers in naively treating these things?

(2) Does this silly idea already exist in literature?

**EDIT**

As a complement to the question here's the graph of the approximation to $f(x)=x$ given by Claude Leibovici's method, which yields
\begin{equation}
g(x) = \frac{1}{12}e^{-2x}-\frac{2}{3}e^{-x}+\frac{2}{3}e^{x}-\frac{1}{12}e^{2x} = \frac{1}{3}\sinh(x)(4-\cosh(x))
\end{equation}
[image: Claude Leibovici's approximant]

Comment: What you have here is certainly interesting, but could you develop a more specific question? The question "any thoughts?" is not exactly easy to answer in an objectively correct way.

Comment: I'll edit the question.

Comment: A somewhat useful (?) application would be turning something in a sum of logarithms which in turn is the log of the product of the arguments....

Comment: It is not silly at all. The problem is with *"infinite-dimensional linear systems "*

Comment: Have a look at the edit with exactly your approach but using the norm

Comment: Thank you for having added the plots.

Comment: Have a look at the update. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that you write
$$x=\sum_{k=-n}^{k=+n} c_k\, e^{k x}$$ instead of Taylor expansions, consider the norm
$$\Phi_n=\int_{-a}^{+a}\Bigg[x-\sum_{k=-n}^{k=+n} c_k\, e^{k x}\Bigg]^2\,dx$$ and minimize it with respect to the $c_k$'s. If we use a symmetric interval, we shall have $c_{k}=-c_{-k}$ and $c_0=0$. So, for the example you gave, consider $a=1$ and $n=2$ and the minimization will lead to
$$c_{-2}=-\frac{3 e^2 \left(7-84 e^2+54 e^4-28 e^6+3 e^8\right)}{1+84 e^2-57 e^4+448 e^6-201 e^8+12   e^{10}+e^{12}}$$
$$c_{-1}=\frac{6 e \left(3+9 e^2+38 e^4+6 e^6-9 e^8+e^{10}\right)}{1+84 e^2-57 e^4+448 e^6-201
   e^8+12 e^{10}+e^{12}}$$ $$\Phi_2=\frac{3 \left(15+324 e^2+134 e^4+804 e^6-405 e^8+40 e^{10}\right)}{1+84 e^2-57 e^4+448
   e^6-201 e^8+12 e^{10}+e^{12}}-\frac{23}{6}=2.75\times 10^{-6}$$ As usual, the maximum error is at the bounds; in this case, it is $3.83\times 10^{-3}$.

Using $n=3$, the norm decreases to $7.37\times 10^{-9}$ (a factor of $373$)

**Edit**

Using as you did the series expansion
$$e^{k x}=1+k x+\frac{k^2 x^2}{2}+\frac{k^3 x^3}{6}+\frac{k^4 x^4}{24}+O\left(x^5\right)$$ and using the same norm to minimize the error, I find
$$x=\frac 1{12}e^{-2x}-\frac 23 e^{-x}+\frac 23 e^{x}-\frac 1{12}e^{2x}=\frac{1}{3} \sinh (x) (4-\cosh (x))$$

Here is a plot with the two approximations (black: minimizer of the norm with exponential functions; red: minimizer of the norm using polynomial expansion of $e^{kx}$)

[image: Claude Leibovici's approximants]

**Update**

Taking into account the above, it means that we make the approximation
$$x_{(n)}=\sum_{k=1}^n c_k \, \sinh(k x)$$ and the parameters are obtained by the minimization of the norm
$$\Phi_n=\int_{-a}^{+a}\Bigg[x-\sum_{k=1}^n c_k \, \sinh(k x)\Bigg]^2\,dx$$ where the hyperbolic sines are either used *per se* or approximated by their Taylor series; the last solution is obviously simpler in terms of apparent "simplicity" of the coefficients.

However, for a given $n$, the results will depend on the number of terms used in the Taylor series. Expanding the  hyperbolic sines to $O\left(x^{2p+1}\right)$,  the coefficients are (still for $a=1$)
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
p & c_1 & c_2 \\
 2 & 1.333333333 & -0.1666666667 \\
 3 & 1.266696757 & -0.1365320137 \\
 4 & 1.260198645 & -0.1337118902 \\
 5 & 1.259839496 & -0.1335590439 \\
\cdots &\cdots &\cdots \\
\infty &1.259826765 &-0.1335536879 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Wow! So it seems that there is a tradeoff between quality of the approximation and ugliness of the coefficients! :)

Comment: @marcotrevi. The coefficients are nice !!! (joke). DId you plot it ?  Do you mind to add this plot of this in the post ? Being blind, I am unable to produce decent plots (same scale as you : $-2 \leq  x \leq 2$) .  Thanks and cheers.

Comment: Of course, I'll be happy to add the plot!

Comment: Sorry claude, I don't understand how you got the coefficients in your edit: could you please tell em the difference between the two derivations?

Comment: I assume you are using the Taylor expansion of $e^x$ in the norm, ending up with a minimization problem that involves only polynomials...is that correct?