# What is the general solution to this linear system?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, determinant

While playing with [this concept](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3511737/does-this-inverse-taylor-series-exist-in-literature), I came around a weird class of matrices, namely $2n\times 2n$ matrices $M_n$ of this form:
$$
M_1 = \left[
\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 \\
-1 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$
$$
M_2 = \left[
\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
-2 & -1 & 1 & 2 \\
4 & 1 & 1 & 4 \\
-8 & -1 & 1 & 8
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$
$$
M_3 = \left[
\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
-3 & -2 & -1 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
9 & 4 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 9 \\
-27 & -8 & -1 & 1 & 8 & 27 \\
81 & 16 & 1 & 1 & 16 & 81 \\
-243 & -32 & -1 & 1 & 32 & 243
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$
i.e. the $k$-th row of matrix $M_n$ is
$$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
(-n)^k & \cdots & (-3)^k & (-2)^k & (-1)^k & 1^k & 2^k & 3^k \cdots & n^k
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$
where $k$ starts from $0$.

My question is if there is a known general explicit solution to the system

$$
M_nx = b
$$

or if anything about these matrices is already known in literature.

For instance, with $b = (b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4)$ the solution for
$$
M_2x = b
$$
is
$$
x = \left[
\begin{matrix}
\frac{1}{12}(-2b_1+b_2+2b_3-b_4)\\
\frac{1}{6}(4b_1-4b_2-b_3+b_4) \\
\frac{1}{6}(4b_1+4b_2-b_3-b_4) \\
\frac{1}{12}(-2b_1-b_2+2b_3+b_4)
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

The eigenvalues for $M_1$ are $1+i$ and $1-i$ but for the other cases they are horrible.

The determinants for the first $M_n$'s are the following:

$$
\det(M_1)=2\\
\det(M_2)=72\\
\det(M_3)=691200
$$

Comment: Did you look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix ?

Comment: Yes I know about Vandermonde matrices but do you think they are closely related?

Comment: I think you can show that the matrix has 2n LI columns, which would imply that it's determinant is non-zero; then the solution is simply $x = M_n^{-1}b$.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to explicitly find the inverse.

Comment: Oh I see. Could you edit that in the question.

Comment: This is a specific polynomial interpolation problem. The solution may be expressed via divided differences using Newton formula.

Comment: @uranix Great! Could you please expand your comment into an answer?

Comment: @marco [See this page](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Inverse_of_Vandermonde_Matrix) regarding the inverse of a Vandermonde matrix. Your matrix is simply the transpose of a Vandermonde matrix, so the same steps can be applied.